# Message campaings sent, but not received on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an iOS app which uses Firebase messaging to manage push notifications. **All notifications work perfectly whenever I use the user token to send the messages directly to the specific device**, from both my own servers, and from Firebase console tests which allow input specific tokens to send test messages to specific devices.

However when I run a Cloud Messaging campaign through the Firebase console to send notifications massively, it does not get received by the users.

I did check the status of the campaign in the Firebase console, I see tens of thousands of messages sent, but zero are received according to the console, and I can confirm they do not get received by checking my own test devices (which otherwise would receive individual messages sent using user token perfectly).

Am I missing anything?